# Set max and min value of variable and limit decimals

Tags: php, max, rounding, min

I have a variable `$percentchance` that represent the percent chance to succeed with something. What I would like help with is, for it to never display above `100` or below `0`.

Currently I have used this `min` function to never go above `100`.

`<?php echo min(100, $percentchance); ?>`

Another issue is that sometimes I get the value of percent like `26.3456`, and I wish for some way to make it round up or round down and display only 2 decimals like `26.35` in that case.

Comment: You can create a function which assigns a new value to `$percentchance` and checks if its new value is above 100. Basically, OOP would help a lot there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set an upper and lower bound for the first problem. The second problem can be tackled with `number_format`.

Example:

```
echo number_format(min(100, max(0, $x)), 2);
```

To enforce always rounding up to the next second digit (e.g. `1.111` would be rounded to `1.12`), you could utilise `ceil`.

```
echo number_format(min(100, max(0, ceil($x*100)/100)), 2);
```

Comment: @mickmackusa `number_format()` rounds like the `round()` function. :-)

Comment: The `ceil` snippet shows how to round up `1.111` to `1.12`.

Comment: The example uses `ceil()` to round up whenever a digit > 0 follows after a specific digit, e.g. the second decimal digit. `round` wouldn't round up when calling `round(1.111, 2)`. `ceil(1.111*100)/100` instead would return `1.12`. It's an example for the ambiguous last sentence of the question. The `$mode` option of `round()` has no solution for that case.

Comment: @mickmackusa When $x=1.111 it should say 1.11 and if $x=1.116 it should say 1.12

Comment: The answer is correct: The first snippet has the expected rounding behaviour and the second one is an addition which shows how to always round up.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to round up with just two decimal use `round()`

```
echo round(26.3456, 2);
```